# How do I schedule tasks on Windows using Python?

Tags: python, windows, schedule

I have the following code:

```
import schedule
import time

def job(t):
    print "I'm working...", t
    return

schedule.every().sunday.at("01:00").do(job,'It is sonday 01:00')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60) # wait one minute
```

How can I make sure the code works when my PC is off or when the code is not running?

I don't know if my question is weird but with schedule, we should be able to repeat the event. And I think it is just the case as long as the code is running.

Or easy, what happens when the code is not running and/or my pc is off?

Comment: which OS you use? (Windows/Linux/Other)

Comment: @balderman Windows

Comment: so why dont you use https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10 ?

Comment: @UserOfStackOverFlow please do not advise users deleting their posts, especially if their posts have answers. You are essentially setting them for a post ban. See [Meta FAQ for details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/16874098). On an off-note, the comment text would benefit from being phrased in a friendlier way.

Comment: @UserOfStackOverFlow I consider the comment you posted to not only be unkind, but it's also misleading.

Comment: @Scratte Not was my intention. Give an upvote for the answer to help future searchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the OS scheduler. In case of windows - go with https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10